# 'tox' and 'pyproject.toml'

Tags: python, setuptools, tox, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to convert a fairly simple python package from using `setup.py` to `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` (unless this becomes so confusing that it's not "worth it", in which case I shall give up - hopefully I won't have to do that!).

My `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = my_pkg
description = My Package
long_description = file: README.md
version = 2.1
author = My Company, Inc.
include_package_data = true

[options]
package_dir =
    =src
packages =
    find:
python_requires = >=3.7
install_requires =
    pandas >= 1.1
    numpy >= 1.14.2
    mock >= 2.0.0
    jsonpickle >= 1.0
    pyyaml >= 3.13
    pycron >= 1.0.0
    importlib_resources >= 1.0.2
    more_itertools >= 8.10
    pytz >= 2021.3
    my_internal_package >= 1.1

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

Note `my_internal_package` there - that's an internal dependency that's hosted on an internal pypi-like server, which requires an entry in `extra-index-url` in my `~/.pip/pip.conf` to find it.

My `tox.ini` looks like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py39-pandas{11,12,13,14}

[testenv]
deps = nose
       coverage
       pandas11: pandas>=1.1,<1.2
       pandas12: pandas>=1.2,<1.3
       pandas13: pandas>=1.3,<1.4
       pandas14: pandas>=1.4,<1.5
commands = python -m coverage run -m nose []
sitepackages = True
```

When I try to run `tox`, I get this output:

```
% tox
ERROR: pyproject.toml file found.
To use a PEP 517 build-backend you are required to configure tox to use an isolated_build:
https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/package.html
```

So I don't quite understand why `isolated_build` is necessary in this situation (I looked at the above URL but I can't connect the dots between "configurable build system" and "isolated virtual environment"), but I add this to the `[tox]` section of `tox.ini`:

```
isolated_build = True
```

(My `pyproject.toml` already has the required `[build-system]` stuff.)

Now, with those added, the `tox` output is:

```
% tox
py39-pandas11 inst-nodeps: /Users/kwilliams/git/optos/my-pkg/.tox/.tmp/package/1/my-pkg-2.1.tar.gz
py39-pandas11 installed: ansicolors==1.1.8,attrs==21.4.0,cachetools==5.0.0,certifi==2021.10.8,cfgv==3.3.1,charset-normalizer==2.0.12,click==8.0.4,clipboard==0.0.4,coverage==6.3.2,deprecation==2.1.0,distlib==0.3.4,docker==5.0.3,my-pkg @ file:///Users/kwilliams/git/optos/my-pkg/.tox/.tmp/package/1/my_pkg-2.1.tar.gz,filelock==3.6.0,gitlab-utils==0.2,google-auth==2.6.0,grpcio==1.44.0,identify==2.4.11,idna==3.3,importlib-resources==5.4.0,inflect==5.4.0,iniconfig==1.1.1,jsonpickle==2.1.0,kubernetes==19.15.0,libretranslatepy==2.1.1,lxml==4.8.0,mock==4.0.3,more-itertools==8.12.0,nodeenv==1.6.0,nose==1.3.7,numpy==1.22.3,oauthlib==3.2.0,packaging==21.3,pandas==1.1.5,platformdirs==2.5.1,pluggy==1.0.0,pre-commit==2.17.0,protobuf==3.19.4,py==1.11.0,pyasn1==0.4.8,pyasn1-modules==0.2.8,pycron==3.0.0,pyparsing==3.0.7,pyperclip==1.8.2,pytest==6.2.5,pytest-asyncio==0.16.0,pytest-grpc==0.8.0,pytest-mock==3.7.0,python-dateutil==2.8.2,pytz==2021.3,PyYAML==6.0,requests==2.27.1,requests-oauthlib==1.3.1,rsa==4.8,six==1.16.0,testcontainers==3.4.2,toml==0.10.2,translate==3.6.1,types-futures==3.3.8,types-protobuf==3.17.5,types-setuptools==57.4.10,urllib3==1.26.8,virtualenv==20.13.3,websocket-client==1.3.1,wrapt==1.14.0,zipp==3.7.0
py39-pandas11 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2767948081'
py39-pandas11 run-test: commands[0] | python -m coverage run -m nose
EEEEEE..E.E........EEE...
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ModuleNotFoundError (No module named 'my_internal_package')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/py39-pandas11/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/py39-pandas11/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 417, in loadTestsFromName
    module = self.importer.importFromPath(
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/py39-pandas11/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/py39-pandas11/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/kwilliams/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/kwilliams/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/src/my_pkg/util/test_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from my_internal_package import Blah, BlahBlah
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_internal_package'

... lots more output like this
```

So it's not trying to install `my_internal_package`, or at least not succeeding.  I've looked at https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html?highlight=isolated#conf-isolated_build to try to understand what this `isolated_build` parameter does, but it doesn't mention anything about how dependencies are found - it only says this:

> **isolated_build=false(true|false)**
> New in version 3.3.0.
> Activate isolated build environment. tox will use a virtual environment to build a source distribution from the source tree. For build tools and arguments use the pyproject.toml file as specified in PEP-517 and PEP-518. To specify the virtual environment Python version define use the isolated_build_env config section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As requested in a comment, my file structure is as follows:

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── NEWS.md
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   ├── my_pkg
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── agent
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── foo.py
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── util
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── test_utils.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── agent
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── test_agent.py
│       │   ├── ...
└── tox.ini
```

Comment: In order to answer your question you need to show the directory structure of your package. But I am pretty sure the issue is that you do not follow the `src` convention, ie put all your source code in a `src` directory, which has no `__init__.py` in it. That way Python cannot import your modules, unless it is installed. Isolated build emulates that behavior, which means, your package worked by chance until now, as Python was able to import the modules directly from the file system - which is usually not intended.

Comment: Recommended reading:
https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/
https://web.archive.org/web/20170615032800/https://enotuniq.org/
https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/08/test-as-installed.html

Comment: @JürgenGmach I do have the source code in `src/` - I'll amend the question to indicate that.  I don't know why that would affect the ability to find prerequisite packages, though.  Thanks for the 3 links too, I'll check them out.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I actually missed that site packages line.

Answer (score 0):

By random jiggerypokery I stumbled upon a solution - get rid of the `sitepackages = True` line in the `tox.ini` file.

No idea why this fixes it.  I only added that line (years ago) because I thought it would speed up building the test environment if it were able to also use stuff from global environments.  According to [the docs](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html), here's its function:

> Set to true if you want to create virtual environments that also have access to globally installed packages.

Doesn't say what "global" means in this context - not in any virtual env?  In the virtual env I'm using for development?

Curiously, the build is actually *much faster without this line*.  It's like the semantics are backwards with respect to the documentation or something - it's installing far fewer prerequisites in the `py39-pandas11 installed:` line:

```
py39-pandas11 inst-nodeps: /Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/.tmp/package/1/mypkg-2.1.tar.gz
py39-pandas11 installed: coverage==6.4.4,my-pkg @ file:///Users/kwilliams/git/my-pkg/.tox/.tmp/package/1/my_pkg-2.1.tar.gz,importlib-resources==5.9.0,jsonpickle==2.2.0,mock==4.0.3,more-itertools==8.14.0,nose==1.3.7,numpy==1.23.3,pandas==1.1.5,pycron==3.0.0,python-dateutil==2.8.2,pytz==2022.2.1,PyYAML==6.0,six==1.16.0, my_internal_package==1.1.1,zipp==3.8.1
py39-pandas11 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2799664931'
py39-pandas11 run-test: commands[0] | python -m coverage run -m nose
.....................................................S..SS...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 61 tests in 2.506s

OK (SKIP=3)
```

Anyway, my build is working fine now.